# Laravel - SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 207 General SQL Server error

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I use Linux and i develop a system with Laravel + SQLServer. But when i try insert a row in db.. this error is displayed

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 207 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [207] (severity 16) [(null)] (SQL: insert into [drm_CADESTUDANTE] ([nomecompleto], [email], [telefone], [idturma], [idcurso], [celular], [updated_at], [created_at]) values (Foo, foo@baar.com.br, 8182595629, 1, 1, 23423409340934, 2016-06-21 01:54:11.000, 2016-06-21 01:54:11.000))
```

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The 207 ERROR show up when you try to put a variable inside your request, first thing to do is to check if the concatenation of your values are good. Don't forget that every values you pass in the request must have single quotes around (except for numerics).

Hope it was helpfull for someone.